# Erro em aplicação WPF, mas apenas em algumas máquinas

Tags: c#, wpf

Fiz uma pequena aplicação para extrair um arquivo .zip. Funciona, porem quando rodo em outras três máquinas, aí não funciona. O erro é esse:

> Ocorreu um erro ao criar arquivo ZIP
>
> Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto

A pergunta é bem simples. Quando vou instalar um aplicativo WPF, preciso instalar alguma outra coisa que não não seja o exe, app.config e as DLL's referenciadas?

Obs: O aplicativo está na rede e todas as máquinas acessam via atalho, apontando para o mesmo lugar(endereço). Preciso fazer alguma coisa mais na máquina local?

Grato a todos desde já.

Comment: Não seria a falta do .Net Framework ?

Comment: Pensei nisso também, mas não posso ficar instalando, tentando. Preciso ter a certeza que é isso e não sei como faço essa verificação.

Comment: É simples, certifique-se de que a versão do .net que compilou o seu projeto é igual ou superior a que está no computador cliente. Por via das dúvidas, instale a versão mais atual referente ao S.O.

Answer (score 2):

Resolvi o problema da seguinte forma. Gerei outro app com mensagens e try..catch em vários lugares(debugar em run time) e vi que na conexão com o BD dava erro. Há uma tag no meu app.config que não estava funcionando.

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="SampleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=serveralpha)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL))) " />
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

Vi que essa `tag` não estava sendo lida. Então, copiei o `TNSNAMES.ora`, removi todas as linhas, deixando apenas as linhas referentes a conexão com esse banco. Dessa forma funcionou. Só não entendi o porquê da dependência do `TNSNAMES` na mesma pasta do `EXE`, mas isso fica para outro post.